# How and when to use paired t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, t-test, inference, paired-data

In a study of the effectiveness of weight loss programs, 47 subjects who were overweight, at least 20% participated in a group support program for 10 weeks. The weight of each subject was taken at the beginning of the program and 6 months after the program. The paired t-test was used to assess whether the average weight loss is significant. t (46) = 4.68, p <0.01.

a) Why was the matched statistic appropriate?

b) The level of signification: α = 0.01. In fact, the results are more significant than what p <0.01 suggests. What can you say about the p-value of this t-test?

c) Explain to someone who does not know the statistics but is interested in
weight loss what is the practical conclusion.

d) Once you have given your explanation in c), how much weight on average can someone expect to lose?

Here, I don't know how to apply the paired t-test? Thank you to explain it to me.

Answer (score -1):

The paired t-test usually tests the hypothesis that the difference between the mean score at pretest and the mean score at posttest, $$H_1: \mu_{pre} \ne \mu_{post}$$

Comment: This misses the fact that you find differences between paired observations and do a one-sample test.

Comment: Also missing the point of explaining to somebody not knowing statistics.